# Подсветка синтаксиса в SSMS

Tags: sql-server

Недавно работал в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17, писал запросы SQL, ничего не ломал, при следующем запуске подсветка синтаксиса пропала. В параметрах шрифты стоят как над (например, там указано, что системную процедуру писать розовым). Вопрос, как решить данную проблему, не прибегая к переустановке?

Comment: проблема решена? как вариант - обновить кэш IntelliSense, перезагрузить ОС если не поможет

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за русского языка, нужно удалить ssms и visual studio isolation, которая ставится под эту ssms, все языковые пакеты, от этой студии.
Если это ssms 17, то нужно удалять по мимо нее visual stuido 2015 isolation